# Is there any way to show a credential dialog integrate with Windows Hello?

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp, windows-hello

I mean, something like this (it was used at `Control Panel > Credential Manager`):

[image: Please verify your credentials to view the stored passwords]

I have tried some APIs:

1. `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` and `CredentialPicker.PickAsync`: It seems good, but there's **no** fingerprint/PIN options.
2. `UserConsentVerifier.RequestVerificationAsync`: It seems good, but there's **only** fingerprint option.

I need to show both `user/password` and `fingerprint/pin` options. Is there any API or Options to show them?

Thanks:)

Comment: Do you want to use windows hello in your app?

Comment: Actually,CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials should do the trick. I was doing this successfully until Windows 1809. When the user hit "More Options" the option to enter PIN or Fingerprint were present. Since 1809 it seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` will often include Windows Hello and PIN code as authentication alternatives if passing `dwFlags=CREDUIWIN_ENUMERATE_CURRENT_USER` as done in the [Chromium sources](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/chrome/browser/password_manager/password_manager_util_win.cc). I've verified this on a "vanilla" Windows 10 21H2 computer.

However, this is not always the case. There seem to be some sort of system policy preventing Windows Hello, PIN code and other authentication provides from showing up on certain (or possibly all) domain-joined computers.